# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cycler'

Tags: windows, matplotlib, pycharm

when I use matplotlib on pycharm without using 'cycler', it shows the above type of error. Could you help? Appreciate!

```
      import cv2 as cv
      import numpy as np
      from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

      img = cv.imread('lena.jpg',-1)
      cv.imshow('image',img)
      img =cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

      plt.imshow(img)
      plt.show(0)

      cv.waitKey(0)
      cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `cycler` is a dependency of matplotlib. So probably something went wrong during installation of matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install cycler using below command:

pip install cycler (if you have pip installed)

If still you are facing same issue:

Please see tutorials: https://youtu.be/PXD7faWtdAg

Comment: You’re using conda? If yes then try “conda install cycler”. If not please tell me what are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to programming. I am not using conda. I just install matplotlib on pycharm and It does not work now.

Comment: Okay, please open cmd run “pip -v” if it show version then run “pip install cycler”

Comment: It show:Requirement already satisfied: cycler in c:\python\lib\site-packages (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from cycler) (1.12.0)

Comment: But ERROR still there

Comment: Try running same command using cmd which you are running using pycharm

Comment: Not sure what do you mean.. I post the entire code above now. Hope it will help.